# how to select a block of elements in a vector

Tags: r

I have the following vector x

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 9, 1)

y <- matrix(NA, 6, 3)
for(i in 1:3){
 y[,i] <- 
}
```

I want the results to be as follows

```
y[,1] = x[-c(1:3),]; y[,2] = x[-c(4:6),]; y[,3] = x[-c(7:9),]
```

I am not quite sure how to do it. I tried to use `TRUE, FALSE` but it did not work.

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can create the index to subset in loop.

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 9, 1)

y <- matrix(NA, 6, 3)
for(i in 1:3){
  n <- i * 3
  y[,i] <- x[-((n-2):n), ]
}
```